# Is Const important for Copy Constructor?

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, copy

I'm running this program on DEV C++ and it's showing error of const.. But In Visual Studio its working fine. Now is const important for copy constructor?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
   /* Class data members */
public:
   Test(Test &t) { /* Copy data members from t*/}
   Test()        { /* Initialize data members */ }
};

Test fun()
{
    cout << "fun() Called\n";
    Test t;
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    Test t1;
    Test t2 = fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is unrelated to copy constructors.

Comment: @juanchopanza it is, second line in `main()` uses copy-initialization and fails to compile.

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, but the problem has nothing to do with copy constructors. I could provide an example where the same error occurs in a matrix inversion.

Comment: Some (especially older) compilers don't enforce the restriction against binding non-`const` references (such as your copy-constructor argument) to temporaries (such as the `Test` returned by `fun()`'s). No big deal, just fix the code so the copy-constructor accepts by `const` reference.  VC++ goes out of its way to avoid breaking old code, unless you provide particular command-line options per the answer to the duplicate.

Comment: @juanchopanza At first I thought OP is also asking if it's legal to have a copy constructor that takes its param. by non-const reference.

Comment: @AsifMushtaq this code compiles since now you are using a lvalue (non-temporary) as the right hand side of the copy constructor in the line `Point p2 = p1;`. Try `Point p2 = Point(0,0);` and it won't compile anymore. But please don't change the code as it makes all answers and comments look completely unrelated to the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The copy constructor is traditionally declared as

```
Foo(const Foo&);
```

since it is assumed that a copy doesn't change the object on its right hand side (at least a good copier shouldn't change it, right?)

In standard C++, you cannot bind a temporary to a non-`const` reference. Visual Studio uses a non-standard extension, and that's why your code compiles, but you should not rely on non-standard extensions.

It is not absolutely necessary to have your copy constructor taking the rhs by `const` reference, it is also OK to take it by reference. But in that case, you won't be able to perform copy initialization from a rvalue (a temporary basically).